# Insert date from a JDateChooser to a MySql database

Tags: java, c#, mysql, sql, jdatechooser

hello I do not know how to insert a date from a JDateChooser into mysql converted for the format that accepts mysql ......
I am working with the MVC fremework ... and I am inserting the data in the following way
....

is my driver class

add a jtxfile just to try to use my application call it

```
txtFecha2 (this.vistaAlumno.getTxtFecha2().getText())
```

in the view I made each of the components their GET and SET methods so that I could use them from another class ...

the JDateChooser is called jdFecha.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == vistaAlumno.getBtnInsertar()) {

            //obtiene ID de producto  this.mimodelo.getDatosVentaxFechas( this.frmconsulta.__fecha1.getDate(), this.frmconsulta.__fecha2.getDate() ) );
            //String cat[] = this.vistaAlumno.__lista_categorias.getSelectedItem().toString().split("-");
            if (this.modeloAlumno.NuevoProducto(
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtMatricula().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtNombre().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtApellido_p().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtApellido_m().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtSexo().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtFecha2().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtDireccion().getText(),
                    this.vistaAlumno.getTxtCorreo().getText()// ,
            // cat[0].trim()
            )) {
                this.vistaAlumno.getJtDatosAlumno().setModel(this.modeloAlumno.getTablaAlumno()); //actualiza JTable
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nuevo Alumno Registrado");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Verifique los datos del nuevo Alumno");
            }
```

greetings and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

well i am not looking at your code but as for adding date from JDateChooser you can use this code

```
String datee=((JTextField)a.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

then you can add it into

```
ps.setString(0,a);
```

in the above code,

> a is JDateChooser
>
> ps is PreparedStatement

hope it helps